# Cluster Segregation in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Clusters have been formed. Now, I am wondering if we can select elements from a particular cluster id. 
Here are the different clusters that are formed .

```
  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
 549  290 1206  103   97  102    2  208  123

  10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18 
  17   75  293  981   23  586   25   15  365
```

Like , I have to chose element from cluster 12. Then, how to do it

This is the code used to form the cluster:

```
db <- dbscan(cbind(Final$event_begin_longitude,Final$event_begin_latitude), .0025, minPts = 1, scale = FALSE, method = "raw")
```

Comment: How are your clusters stored? Is each cluster a data frame? Please post example code.

Comment: Information "Clusters have been formed." is insufficient for others to reproduce your problem. Noone knows what functions and packages did you use to form clusters. Please edit your answer. You may read some StackOverflow help abouthow to ask a good question.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Here goes the code!!!

Comment: Do you need any more information ?? @cure

Comment: What is dbscan? What is the class of db?

Comment: DBSCAN is a clustering algorithm which clusters data based on the relative density. It takes S3 method for class.

Comment: `dbscan` comes from the package `dbscan` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no predefined method to access elements of a cluster. However, you can easily do it yourself. The return value of `dbscan` has a slot named `clusters`, which is in the same order as your input:

```
dta <- structure(list(V1 = c(0, 0.04, 0.09, 0.13, 0.17, 0.22, 0.26, 0.3, 0.35, 0.39, 0.43, 0.48, 0.52, 0.57, 0.61, 0.65, 0.7, 0.74, 0.78, 0.83, 0.87, 0.91, 0.96, 1), 
                  V2 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.03, 0.01, 0.05, 0.45, 0.73, 0.91, 0.9, 0.67, 0.77, 0.98, 0.94, 0.86, 1, 0.38, 0.09, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0)), 
             .Names = c("V1", "V2"), 
             row.names = c(NA, -24L), 
             class = "data.frame")

db <- dbscan::dbscan(dta, .25, minPts = 1)

# Combine values and their cluster
cbind(dta, db$cluster)

# Plot with colored clusters
plot(dta, col = db$cluster, pch = 16)
```

[image: DBSCAN cluster color coded plot]